# What is the best way to evenly scale one byte?

Tags: c, integer

In C I need to scale a `uint8_t` from 0 - 255 to 0 - 31

What is the best way to do this evenly?

Comment: A uint8_t isn't 256 bits - it's 8 bits. Could you give more information?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by scale?

Comment: 256 bits was totally wrong, updated question, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're trying to scale from 8 bits to 5 bits, you can do a 3 bit shift;

```
uint8_t scaled = (uint8_t)(original >> 3);
```

This drops the lower 3 bits.

Comment: I think the rounded value will fail if you have an original which is above (255 - 15).

Comment: @Laserallan: Lol, I noticed that too!  (I must have been editing while you made the comment)

Comment: Don't round. Your first answer is the right one I think. It evenly distributes the results.

Comment: yeah i think the cast isn't necassary: promotion takes care of converting it to int automagically ("usual arithmetical conversions"). so you have now (int)(uint16_t)original + 4 effectively. without the cast, you have  ((int)original + 4) . u get overflow if you do something like  original += 4.

Comment: if your int is 32 bits, anyway :) if you got a 16bit int, then both will be converted to (unsigned int) with your explicit cast to uint16_t first :). but both will be int without an explicit cast because int at least has 16bits. anyway, i won't appear as a nitpicker so i +1 you as it is :)

Comment: Mathematically, shifting 3 bits is the same as a floor(N/8).  In this case, it can be thought of as putting 256 values from an 8-bit integer into 32 groups, where each value in a group is numbered 0-7.  The lowest 3 bits then don't matter as they only identify a value within a group.

Comment: @Jason: I agree that the rounding is both unnecessary and is in fact wrong (255 for example would become 0!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use some simple multiplication and division:

```
uint8_t scaled = (uint8_t)(((uint32_t)original * 32U) / 256U);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but may want to cast original to something larger to avoid truncation due to overflow with that * 32.

Comment: FYI, This answer is the same as scaled = (original << 5) >> 8, which is the same as scale = original >> 3, which is the same as the accepted answer.